# Why doesn't my swift ui view update after I change a State var?

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to Swift development, and I'm trying to make a View, where you can click an item and it gets bigger, while the old big item gets smaller. I'm using an @State var called chosen to know which Element should be big at the moment. The items itself are Views with a Button on top. The idea is, that I click the button and the button will change the chosen variable, which is working. But it seems that my view doesn't redraw itself and everything stays as is. The simplified pseudocode looks like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var chosen = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            ForEach(0 ..< 4) { number in
                if self.chosen == number {
                        DifferentView()
                            .frame(big)
                            .clipShape(big)
                }else{
                    ZStack{
                        DifferentView()
                            .frame(small)
                            .clipShape(small)
                        Button(action: {self.chosen = number}){Rectangle()}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are `big`, `small`, and could you include `DifferentView`?

Comment: big and small are just abbreviations for function inputs creating big or small frames. I don't really want to include Different View, I hope the code is still understandable and good to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using this overload of `ForEach.init(_:content:)`, which accepts a constant range. While your range doesn't change, it also appears to be that this `ForEach` variant doesn't update the content (it was surprising to me).

You need to use the following overload: `ForEach.init(_:id:content:)` - supplying `id` with a keypath:

```
ForEach(0 ..< 4, id: \.self) { number in
  // ...
}
```

But because there is a conditional, it trips up SwiftUI (hard to know why). The way to avoid it is to wrap it in something, like a `Group` or a `ZStack`, or even a function that generates the inner view:

```
ForEach(0 ..< 4, id: \.self) { number in
  Group {
    self.chosen == number {
       // ...
    } else {
       // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Or, like so:

```
ForEach(0 ..< 4, id: \.self) { number in
   self.inner(for: number)
}
```

```
@ViewBuilder
func inner(for number: Int) -> some View {
  self.chosen == number {
     // ...
  } else {
     // ...
  }
}
```